# generating integers from a list of real numbers that came out of distribution

Tags: r, probability

My model generates numbers, say x= 0.2719094. In the output, this is supposed to be an integer (that follows Poisson distribution, which is accounted for in the generation) mostly 0s, some 1s and a little of 2+. My idea is to round this x= 0.2719094 to one of the 2 closest integers with uniform weighting. These numbers are in a column and I would like to generate a column output of integers.

TLDR example:
how to generate integers from

x= 0.2: would be 80% to become 0 and 20% to become 1

x= 1.2: 80% to become 1 and 20% to become 2

I am not sure how to answer this question. A solution preferably in `R` (or `python`/`excel`) would be nice.

Comment: check the `sample` R function.

Comment: Why do you think you need to round the predictions to integers?

Comment: My predictions are supposed to be number of events 0,1,2,... following poisson process being heavy towards 0s and 1s

Comment: Just because your observations are integers does not necessarily mean that your predictions need to be integers. It depends on what you are trying to predict, which is intimately connected to your loss function ([Kolassa, 2020](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.ijforecast.2019.02.017)). ...

Comment: ... If you want the expectation (minimizing the MSE), that will be non-integer. If you want a quantile (minimizing a pinball loss, and the median will minimize the MAE), that will be integer. If you want the most likely value (minimizing a 0-1 loss), that will again be an integer, but different from the median. Your model most likely minimizes the MSE, so it attempts to give you an unbiased expectation forecast - but rounding this in some way will not give you a specific one of these integer *functionals*. ...

Comment: ... So I would very much recommend you think about just *why* you want an integer prediction (as above, it may make sense, but we don't know enough), and *what kind* you want.

Comment: Just as an example: if you have a Poisson distribution with mean $\lambda=0.7$, then your expectation will be 0.7, the median will be 1, and the mode (the most likely value) will be 0.

Comment: I predict that 0.51 of the people born in the world this year will be female.  Must I round that to 100%??

Comment: I think the issue was that i indeed was building by MSE while wanting integer case predictions. I want them to be an integer because i am interested if the event happens and how many times. I use this output as an input into next step of predictions and if i use just expectation it turns into just average mumbojumbo of whole data without any insight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be nice if you provide some motivation behind this question since, as such, it seems an implementation issue. However, the question can be solved using the `sample` function of `R`.

For

> TLDR example: how to generate integer from
>
> x= 0.2: would be 80% to become 0 and 20% to become 1

run

```
sample(0:1, 1, prob= c(0.2, 0.8))
```

For

> TLDR example: how to generate integer from
>
> x= 0.2: that would be 80% to become 0 and 20% to become 1

you can use

```
sample(1:2, 1, prob= c(0.8, 0.2))
```

As per your request, here is a simple function that generates the random integer from a given the real $x>0$.

```
# x is a number in decimal form, i.e. x = n.d
sep_num <- function(x) {
  n = floor(x)
  d = x - n 
  return(c(integer = n, decimal = d))
}
sep_num(3.142)

convert_to_int <- function(x) {
  oo = sep_num(x)
  prob = oo[2]
  rr = c(oo[1], oo[1]+1)
  sample(x = rr, size = 1, prob = c(prob, 1-prob))
}

> convert_to_int(3.142)
integer 
      4
```

Note that the function is not vectorized, thus if you have a vector or list of values you have to apply a loop, e.g. a `for` loop, `lapply`, `sapply`, etc.

Comment: How can I apply sample to a list of numbers? I guess instead of 0:1 I can use floor:ceiling and prob= c(1-x, x)?

I am building a model to predict integer outcomes but my choises made generate reals.

Comment: @max check the edited answer.

Comment: thanks, I took your suggestion to use sample and iterate.
  a= floor(list[i])
  b= ceiling(list[i])
  list[i]= sample(c(a,b),size= 1, prob= c(b - list[i], list[i] - a))